# How to prove some identities about infinite product?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, elliptic-functions

Recently, I read one paper titled [Modular equations and approximations to π](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram06.pdf) by Ramanujan, in which there are some formulas for $q=\pi i \tau$( where $\tau=x+yi, y>0$, hence $|q|<1)$ :

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+q^{2n-1}\right)=2^{\frac{1}{6}}  q^{\frac{1}{24}}(kk')^{-\frac{1}{12}} ~~~  (1)$$

and 
$$ \prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-q^{2n-1}\right)= 2^{\frac{1}{6}}  q^{\frac{1}{24}}k^{-\frac{1}{12}}k'^{\frac{1}{6}} ~~~~(2)$$

where $k=k(\tau)$ is the Jacobi modulus，   $k^2(\tau)=\lambda(\tau)$, the elliptic modular function, and $k'=\sqrt{1-k^2}.$

The following result can be calculated by Mathematica:
$$\left(1+e^{-\pi  }\right)\left(1+e^{-3 \pi  }\right)\left(1+e^{-5 \pi  }\right) \cdots=2^{\frac{1}{4}} e^{-\pi   / 24}.$$

But I do not know how to prove these formulas (1) and (2). I would appreciate if someone could give some suggestions.

Comment: Also posted to m.se, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634037/how-to-prove-these-formulas-about-infinite-product without notification to either site, a violation of site norms.

Comment: I guess you want to say $q=e^{\pi i \tau}$...

Comment: Second one is $q^{1/24} \eta(q) / \eta(q^2) $ and first one is $q^{1/24} (\eta(q^2)/ \eta(q) )/ (\eta(q^4)/ \eta(q^2)) $ by matching terms in infinite products. So you want to match the eta quotients with the $k$ and $k'$.

Comment: What is $\eta(q)$?

Comment: The Dedekind $\eta$-function, most likely. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function

Comment: @WillSawin  What is the relation  between  eta function $\eta(q)$ and the modulus $k$?

Comment: If I knew more I would have posted it. Both are modular forms, I think...

Comment: Express $k$ and $k'$ in terms of Jacobi theta functions (see the Wikipedia page on Jacobi elliptic functions) then look up product formulae for Jacobi theta functions derived via the Jacobi triple product identity.

Comment: @JeffHarvey Yes, right. I  got it by this way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jacob.Z.Lee when you have time please post how you proved these identities, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First， by theta function  we have $$ k=\frac{\theta_2}{\theta_3},k'=\frac{\theta_4}{\theta_3},$$ where 
$$ \theta_2=2q^{\frac{1}{4}} G \prod (1+q^{2n})^2; ~(1)$$
$$ \theta_3=  G \prod (1+q^{2n-1})^2;(2)$$
$$ \theta_4=  G \prod (1-q^{2n-1})^2;(3)$$
and 
$$ G= \prod (1-q^{2n})^2.$$

So we have $RHS=2^{\frac{1}{6}}q^{\frac{1}{24}}(\frac{\theta_2 \theta_4}{\theta^2_3})^{-\frac{1}{6}}=(\frac{2\theta_3^2}{\theta_2\theta_4})^{\frac{1}{6}}q^{\frac{1}{24}}.$

It is enough to prove the following :

$$ \prod(1+q^{2n-1})^2=(\frac{2\theta_3^2}{\theta_2\theta_4})^{\frac{1}{3}}q^{\frac{1}{12}}$$
Put (1),(2),(3) into the above identity, Jacobi triple product Identity is obtained. Hence the result is established.

Comment: I think there is exponent of two missing on theta 3 after the RHS, thanks again for posting the proof.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks.